# Relative paths from directory

Tags: html

We have a qa/dev server and a prod server. The two differ by a directory like this

```
https://domain/service/envQA/sitename
https://domain/service/env/sitename
```

In some static html I'm trying to put in src and href that are relative to avoid having the markup reference QA if a developer migrates the content and doesn't update an absolute path that includes the envQA. We aren't very fancy and just move most documents over by hand and a busy developer might miss a reference in the middle of several pages of markup -- it happens.

So I'm trying to use relative paths like this.

```
<img src="assets/backgroundimg.png" />
```

This works when the user is at our homepage url of `https://domain/service/env/sitename` but unfortunately our site also has navigational elements that return the user to `https://domain/service/env/sitename/` (note the closing slash).

Is there any way (without javascript) to handle a relative path that would work from either of those "locations"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the `<base>` tag?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

This would allow you to set a base per environment allowing configuring all urls at once.

Comment: Thank you. I had known about <base> for setting the _target, but never knew about this use. This is all in SharePoint and we have to take IE11 into account, but I think this will do the trick!!!